# Regular expression to include all characters except a particular word

Tags: php, regex

I want to filter out a certain pattern using regex.

**Given string:** [video url:http:\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] Then some text goes here then again [video url:http:\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] and some more text following this.

**Required O/P:** Then some text goes here then again and some more text following this.

**Language:** PHP

**What I tried:**

```
$text='[video url:http:\\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] Then some text goes here then again [video url:http:\\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] and some more text following this.';
$op = reg_replace('/\[video(.*)\]/','',$text);
echo $op
```

**The o/p that I get:**

and some more text following this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern is greedy, the `.*` matches all it can. You need to change the match to

```
\[video[^\]]++]
```

i.e. an opening bracket followed by any number of items that are not a closing bracket followed by a single closing bracket.

So the code will look like

```
$op = reg_replace('/\[video[^\]]++]/','',$text);
```

This pattern is also possessive (`++`) which will greatly reduce backtracking in the regex engine and speed things up.

Comment: Thanks @bmorris
There can be square brackets in the intermediate text, but if opening bracket is followed by the word **video** then everything following it upto closing **]** must get removed

Comment: Correct me if where I'm wrong in understanding the pattern:

(1) \[video : This denotes pattern starting with **[video**
(2) [^\]]   : This denote anything other than **]**
(3) ++]     : Is this followed by **]** ? If yes then what does ++ means? Though you told it reduce backtracking but I'm still confused about it.

Comment: the final `]` is just a literal - there is no need to escape it. The `++` is two things. The first `+` is "repeated one or more times", the second `+` is "possessively". This means that once matched a character cannot be unmatched. Take a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Answer (score 2):

I changed the pattern a bit :

```
$text='[video url:http:\\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] Then some text goes here then again [video url:http:\\ddf.sd.com asd:fgfggh] and some more text following this.';
$op = reg_replace('/\[video.*?\]/','',$text);
echo $op;
```

Comment: Thanks @Yazmat
I'm new to regex, can please explain the change that you made in the pattern?

Comment: ok What I did is remove the parentheses since you don't need them (you are not capturing anything), and add a `?` after the `*` so that the quantifier `*` become ungreedy (lazy)

Comment: lazy meens that the quantifier will stop at the first match it finds for the next character unlike greedy wich continues to the last one

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no square brackets in the urls, you could use

```
'/\[video[^\]]*\]/'
```

Your original regex doesn't work because the `.*` will greedily match all characters up to the final `]`.